# How to know the resolution screen width and height when i have dual head or triple head from one PC?

Tags: java, linux, video, xorg

I have dual head (VGA output, DVI or HDMI output) from 1 PC using this `xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1`. Each having 1024x768 resolution.

When i use this using Java:

```
screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

I get a huge two screen width together. As a result my Width and height is huge. 
Where i only need to place my application in one screen either VGA or DVI. But using Java how do i know that?

How do i tell that using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() ?

Example: (my application has to run where Java is labeled)

[image]

**Test.java**

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
      GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
      GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
      for (int i = 0; i < screenDevices.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(screenDevices[i].getIDstring());

        DisplayMode dm = screenDevices[i].getDisplayMode();
        int screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = dm.getHeight(); 

        System.out.println("Cake: " + screenWidth + " " + screenHeight);
      }      
  }
}

Output:

:0.0
Cake: 1024 768
:0.1
Cake: 1024 768
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()
```

is what you are looking for. And then from there you can iterate through the screens and get the screen dimension by `getDisplayMode()`